# django How to randomly merge two different querysets (but with some fields in common)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am using Django 3.2

I have two models that look a bit like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    image = models.ImageField()

    # ... other fields unique to this model only


class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    image = models.ImageField()

    # ... other fields unique to this model only
```

I want to be able to write a function like this:

```
def get_modelA_records_with_randomly_inserted_modelB(criteria_for_A, criteria_for_B, page_num):
    qs_A = get_records_for_modelA(criteria_for_A, page_num)
    qs_B = get_records_for_modelB(criteria_for_B, page_num)

    # Randomly insert records of B into list of records of A
    new_qs = qs_A | qs_B # how?
```

A trivial way to do this would be to laboriously iterate through `qs_A`, inserting `qs_B` elements based on a random boolean flag - but I'm wondering is there a more pythonic or "djangoistic" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not at a PC where I can test this right now, but I think you could probably do:

```
new_qs = qs_a | qs_b
new_qs = new_qs.order_by('?')
```

Querysets are lazily evaluated, so as long as you don't try and use this (iterate over it) until you've randomly ordered it, I think this should work.